# Counting cuspidal representations using polynomials

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups

In Zelevinsky's book *Representations of Finite Classical Groups* there is the following result: (See Page~131.)

**Proposition.** (Let's assume that $n\geq 2$.) The number of cuspidal irreducible representations of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ is the number of monic degree $n$ irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_q$.

The argument there is based on Zelevinsky's structure theorem on a class of Hopf $\mathbb{Z}$-algebras (called PSH-algebras) and an understanding of cyclic modules over PID, so it does not seem adapt to other reductive groups in an apparent way.

**Question.** Are there analogues for other finite reductive groups?

It would be great if there is a Lie-theoretic (say, Deligne--Lusztig theoretic) treatment dealing with a wide class of groups in a uniform way, but case-by-case approaches are also welcome!

Comment: For $G=GL_n$, I think that's the same as the number of conjugacy classes in $G$ whose centralizer is an anisotropic maximal torus. Probably it's too ambitious to expect the same thing to hold for general $G$, but it might be a starting point...